# How to send a image jpg/png file from react to express server

Tags: reactjs, image, express, upload

I am trying to send an object from react to express server using node.js

this is my object:

```
const formData = {
    location: location,
    cost: cost,
    email: email,
    image: image,
  };
```

This is my fetch post method :

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/places", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify(formData),
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    if (data.insertedId) {
      alert("Plcae added successfully");
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
```

I can see the image file object in client site console but I am not getting that in expreess server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send your input data as [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to share images/files to the backend.

```
function uploadImage() {
  let formData = new FormData(yourFormData);
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/places", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  }).then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    if (data.insertedId) {
      alert("Plcae added successfully");
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  });
}
```